# Replication between mysql in local and mysql in AWS cloud

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have 2 ways replication between local database and cloud database in MYSQL?

for example any update on local DB (MySQL or MS SQL) will be replicated to database on Amazon Cloud and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct mysqld on EC2, Simply YES. It called Master-Master Replication.

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-master-master-replication/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, enabling replication between local and remote is quite costlier operations which needs :

- your local network should have a **static ip** or some **open-dns** configuration required to keep your ip accessible from anywhere
- higher or moderate bandwidth, if **payload** is **heavy** as well as the **frequency of transactions** on both of your server (in Master-Master mode)

Secondly, if you are using this approach for deploying production setup, I would not recommend such idea, since it make the system maintenance more expensive.